# Is there any way in Blender to animate two scene in same view port

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, units

I need to animate a short movie like:
One person talking to other over phone.
Seller in a shop
And one person in Home.
Please see first person in first scene below image.

[image: This is scene 1]

Similarly the other person will be in shop.

I need to know how to animate these two people talking efficiently. With least sync issues etc as the screen will change 10s of time from one person to other

Comment: Are you referring to video elements to 3d scenes. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question, and add more information that might help us understand what you want to do. Add some sample images as well.

Comment: Hi cegaton thank you for your quick response, I did as you said now let me know how quickly I can achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve those side-by-side comic book style sequences of two overlapping videos of each person talking on the phone? Those would generally be achieved in post production, through compositing video sequences, not directly from a 3D scene.

Comment: Not for comics, but for real ordinary video movie where scene changes one by one. I found a solution though like Hiding one scene and other etc.

Comment: Thus my question simply asking, how to switch entire scene with other in 3d View port. I hope hiding will work, what you think, thank you.